# How can I pass keyword arguments to the `range` function from within another function and maintain user flexibility with Julia?

Tags: function, methods, julia, keyword-argument, multiple-dispatch

I am writing my first module in Julia. I have a function `f` which will use a vector or range for some calculations. I would like to create a method of this function which will create a range using the `range` function before proceeding with the calculations in order to provide some flexibility to the user.

I have written the following:

```
# Attempt 1
function f(x,start,stop;length=1001,step=0.1)
    r=range(start,stop,length=length,step=step)
    # do more stuff with x and r
end
# error: length and step don't agree
```

However, `range` will accept only one of either `step` or `length`. It cannot take both unless they are defined in agreement. This leads me to want to define another function `g` which will be called inside of `f`. `g` would call `range` and have methods to account for the three possible scenarios.

1. User specifies `length` when calling `f`.
2. User specifies `step` when calling `f`.
3. User specifies neither `length` nor `step` when calling `f`, so a default `step` value is used.

I'd rather not create more methods of `f` to avoid copying `#do more stuff with x and r` excessively. I would also like to avoid `if` statements where possible to take advantage of multiple dispatch and be efficient. Although, I haven't come up with any solutions so far.

I cannot define multiple methods of `g` with keyword arguments since the keyword arguments are optional.

```
# Attempt 2
function g(start,stop;length=1001)
    r=range(start,stop,length=length)
end
function g(start,stop;step=0.1)
    r=range(start,stop,step=step)
end
# error: the method definitions overlap
```

I also cannot convert the keyword arguments to regular arguments because I won't know which argument to pass.

```
# Attempt 3
function g(start,stop,length)
    r=range(start,stop,length=length)
end
function g(start,stop,step)
    r=range(start,stop,step=step)
end
function f(x,start,stop;length=1001,step=0.1)
    r=g(start,stop,y)
end
# error: no way to determine y or to differentiate length from step when passed to g
```

Comment: There is no need to force multiple dispatch on everything you do in Julia. A quick look into the Julia code base makes clear that multiple dispatch doesn't replace `if`.

Comment: One thing you could do is to not specify the kwargs, but rather have a signature `f(x,start,stop; kwargs...)` and then splat them into `range` like this: `r = range(start, stop; kwargs...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` function uses `nothing` for `step`/`length` when they are not specified, so the following should work for you:

```
function f(start, stop; step=nothing, length=nothing)
    if step === length === nothing
        step = 0.1 # default step
    end
    r = range(start, stop; step=step, length=length)
    return r
end
```

Examples:

```
julia> f(1, 2; step=0.2)
1.0:0.2:2.0

julia> f(1, 2; length=3)
1.0:0.5:2.0

julia> f(1, 2) # default step
1.0:0.1:2.0
```

---

> I'd rather not create more methods of f to avoid copying #do more
>   stuff with x and r excessively

A somewhat common pattern is to move the core functionality to another function, say `_f`, and have multiple entrypoints `f` which constructs the correct arguments for `_f`. Here is a sketch of that:

```
function f(x, y)
    # construct arguments with x and y
    args = ...
    return _f(args...)
end

function f(x, y, z)
    # construct arguments with x, y and z
    args = ...
    return _f(args...)
end

function _f(args...)
    # core computation
end
```

Comment: Beautiful! Can you explain why `===` is required here rather than just `==`?

Comment: The compiler just really loves `===` for singletons like `nothing`, but `==` would work too. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Checking-for-equality-with-a-singleton-1.